# Naming of CSS property names for JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8

On the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph) I find the following statement:

> Naming conventions have been established for deriving CSS style class names from JavaFX class names, and for deriving CSS property names from JavaFX variable names. [...] The convention for mapping JavaFX variable names to CSS property names is similar, with the addition of the "-fx-" prefix. For example, the blendMode variable would have a corresponding CSS property name of "-fx-blend-mode".

I am not sure if I understand that correctly.

I give some of my controls the ability to be configured via CSS as well. For example, in a number field, I can set the lower and upper boundary for the settable value, the display format (integer, decimal, scientific), the unit which is displayed in the control etc. Should I name them, according to the paragraph above, as

```
-fx-lower-boundary
-fx-upper-boundary
-fx-unit
-fx-mode
```

or does this paragraph only describe the behaviour of the controls from the standard library and I am supposed to choose a vendor prefix different from `-fx-` (such as my company name)?

Comment: In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/package-summary.html) for classes in the  `javafx.css` package, the examples generally use a prefix `-my-...`, which (sort of) suggests that you are supposed to use your own prefix. I don't know of a definitive answer though.

Comment: @James_D Indeed. While not all classes have documenting code, [CssMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/CssMetaData.html) has, and seems to suggest that I should use my own prefix. That's all I wanted to know - if you want, you can turn it into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is not a definitive answer, by any means, the documentation for some of the classes in the `javafx.css` package (for example, [`StylablePropertyFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/StyleablePropertyFactory.html)) contains examples of custom controls with stylable properties. In those examples, the documentation author uses a prefix

```
-my-...
```

for the CSS property names, which suggests you should use your own prefix, and not

```
-fx-...
```

However, I am not aware of anywhere this is made explicit.

Comment: Thanks again, that's all I need to be on the safe side. I just do the same and take an own prefix.

Answer (score -2):

CSS has nothing to do with controls. Cascading Style Sheets format the look and feel of your user interface. That paragraph describes how many JavaFX-specific CSS property names have been derived from the variable and class names of JavaFX.

CSS properties can't be defined by the user. Changing the functionality or behavior of your user interface should be done in your Java code.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/package-summary.html) for the classes in the `javafx.css` package explicitly describe [how to create CSS-stylable properties for custom controls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/StyleablePropertyFactory.html). The package documentation states *"Provides API for making properties styleable via CSS and for supporting pseudo-class state."*

Comment: If they couldn't be defined by the user, I wouldn't have asked... It is explicitly supported to do so.

Comment: "Cascading Style Sheets format the look and feel of your user interface." Right. And how? By modifying the property of the respective controls. So "CSS has nothing to do with controls." isn't correct as well.